# how do i perform root actions from non-root account?

Tags: linux, security, web-server, root

I want to be able to restart services from a php-script. running under the www-user account.

What's the preferred way to perform these actions?

I recon I can place create a file with que'd commands, read by CRON, but the solution itches.

What I'm thinking of is a tiny service, running under root, allowing predefined "methods" so arbitrary root actions cannot be executed.

Any tool out there for this?

Comment: @MadHatter, Mona Lisa sends her greetings, ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could reinvent the wheel, but honestly, I use passwordless sudo for this.  For example, my monitoring system needs to be able to run a command to check the hardware RAID.  This requires root privilege, but I don't want to run the whole monitoring system as root, so instead I have in `sudoers` a line that says

```
nagios  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_md_raid
```

and then run the command `sudo /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_md_raid` as the monitoring user, when I need to check the RAID.

You could have a sudoers line that said

```
www-user    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /etc/rc.d/init.d/myservice
```

then have php execute `sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/myservice restart`.

Comment: This is the way to go IMO.  I used this process for a similar task.  It's been in production for over 3 years now.  Nothing has ever failed and the security risk is almost non-existent as long as you protect the PHP code that triggers it properly with your application logic.

Comment: Thanks, sudoers new to me and bang on target. @Andrew, thanks for the additional info.

Comment: user65927, forgive me if this isn't news to you, but local etiquette is that when you have a satisfactory answer to a question you accept it by clicking on the tick outline next to it.

Comment: You may also need to comment out the line "Defaults    requiretty" in your sudoers file.  This step has gotten me a few times. (E.g. change "Defaults    requiretty" to "#Defaults    requiretty")

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [sudo](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/): it allows to specify actions that can be performed as another user (root in your case).

You can for example add to your`/etc/sudoers` (don't edit the file directly use `visudo`)

```
www-user-account ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mypredefinedaction
```

See `man sudo` for the details and syntax of the file

Comment: be VERY careful when you edit the `/etc/sudoers` file. If it is in any way syntactically incorrect, changing it back is a nightmare b/c you need to `sudo` back into it, but you can't b/c you just wiped out sudo. You end up having to use a rescue CD/DVD and mount the partition manually.

Comment: @puk Actually to edit shudders you need root access and in case the file is damaged you can log in as root and then restore it (from a backup copy) or fix it manually. visudo also performs sanity checks on the file before writing it.

Comment: what is `shudders`? It's true visudo does sanity checks, but they don't help after the damage is done :P